# How I can know X value of point (X, Y) in chart and I know the value of Y C#?

Tags: c#, charts

How can I search for X-value in knowing a certain point, I know the value of Y
I want the function to automatically search for the X value when given the value of Y on chart C#!
i use this `chart1.Series["E.P"].Points.FindMinByValue().YValues.ToString());` to know the Minvalue of Y axis i want to know the X value n this case (Xvalue, YminValue).
how i can know x value when y min value in chart c#

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You get the DataPoint already by using FindMinByValue so if you assign it first:

```
 var dataPoint = chart1.Series["E.P"].Points.FindMinByValue();
```

You can then access the relevant X and Y values like so:

```
 var x = dataPoint.XValue;
 var yVals = dataPoint.YValues;
```

Comment: when i use this X value always = 0

Comment: i want to know value of X when Y is MinValue.

Comment: or how h know x value when i have y value of any point on the chart

Comment: var x = dataPoint.XValue where yVals is minValue are u understand what i mean ?